# Как поменять все четные ключи массива на нечетные и наоборот?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, а нужно получить `[2, 1, 4, 3]`. Может в php есть готовое решение? А если нет, то можно пожалуйста пример такой функции.

Comment: если у вас всего 4 элемента, то проще руками местами поменять. и какой в этом собственно смысл?

Comment: И меняете вы не ключи, а значения ;)

Comment: @Visman дак видимо предполагается, что `[10,20,30,40]` перейдет в `[20,10,40,30]`. неудачный пример данных

Comment: @teran да, это нужно для автоматизации процесса.

Comment: циклом от 1 до длины массива с шагом 2 и меняете местами i и i+1 элемент, например через временную переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$a_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
$a_2 = [];

for ($j = count($a_1), $i = 0, $k = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
    $k = $i & 1 ? $k - 1 : $i + 1;
    empty($a_1[$k]) ?: $a_2[] = $a_1[$k];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($a_2); echo '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Собсно вот. Но здесь я предположил, что в массиве первый ключ 0, пропущенных ключей нет и количество элементов четное. Если количество элементов нечетное, то, во-первых, вылетит notice; во-вторых, предпоследний элемент станет null, а последний - ну тот который был последним в изначальном массиве.

```
$a = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 /*, 17*/];
for($i = 0; $i < count($a) / 2; $i++) {
    $b = $a[$i * 2];
    $a[$i * 2] = $a[$i * 2 + 1];
    $a[$i * 2 + 1] = $b;
}
var_dump($a);
```